# Scrolling a ScrollView to a specific id

Tags: java, android, scrollview

I have a Scrollview in my activity , I want when I press a button the view scrolls down to a specific ID in the view. After some search here I found I can use this code

```
scrollView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            scrollView.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
        }
    });
```

but it scrolls all the page down. I want to scroll to a specific ID in the middle of the view

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
ScrollView scrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scroll_view);
scrollView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
          scrollView.scrollTo(0, (int)view.getY());
     }
}, 100);
```

view = your view you want to scroll to

Comment: Most of the time you want to use postDelayed with scrollview scroll to functions to make sure all the views are already added..

Answer (score -1):

You can do this as below:

```
private void smartScrollToPosition(ListView listView, int desiredPosition) {
    //Write your logic here.
    listView.smoothScrollToPosition(desiredPosition);
}
```

On button handler you can call this as follows

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lessonsListView);
smartScrollToPosition(listView, 0); // scroll to top
return true;
```